# Python 2.7.5 Some trouble with the OR operator

Tags: python, comparison-operators

So, I'm reworking the tic-tac-toe game that I recently created to have more concise and optimized code. However, I'm having some trouble with an OR statement when having either player move on an empty space

(Few quick sidenotes: In my code, user_team and computer_team are equal to either 'X' or 'O' depending on which team the player chooses, and each space on the board equal to ' ' by default)

If I run the code as such:

```
move = int(raw_input('Where would you like to move? (Enter a number from 1-9) \n'))
if 0 < move < 10:
    if board[move] == user_team:
        print ('That space is already taken by a player.'
               'Please select an open space \n')
        user_turn()
    elif board[move] == computer_team:
        print ('That space is already taken by a player.'
               'Please select an open space \n')
    else:
        board[move] = computer_team
        print
else:
    print ('That is not a valid move. Please try again. \n')
    computer_turn()
```

The above code runs exactly as expected and will assign the player move to empty spaces, or refuse if the space is taken.

However, if I shorten the code like this:

```
move = int(raw_input('Where would you like to move? (Enter a number from 1-9) \n'))
if 0 < move < 10:
    if board[move] == user_team or computer_team:
        print ('That space is already taken by a player. '
               'Please select an open space \n')
        user_turn()
    else:
        board[move] = computer_team
        print
else:
    print ('That is not a valid move. Please try again. \n')
```

Then the code will prevent a player from taking an empty space. In essence, the code is saying:

```
if ' ' == 'X' or 'O':
```

but it acts as if it is true, even though it is clearly false.

SideNote: Just in case anyone asks, this is how I draw my board:

```
def draw_board():
print '', board[1], '|', board[2], '|', board[3], \
      '\n-----------\n', \
      '', board[4], '|', board[5], '|', board[6], \
      '\n-----------\n', \
      '', board[7], '|', board[8], '|', board[9], \
      '\n'
```

and board is a list of ten `' '`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
if board[move] == user_team or computer_team:
```

to

```
if board[move] in [user_team, computer_team]:
```

This `if board[move] == user_team or computer_team` will be evaluated as `(board[move] == user_team) or (computer_team)`, since `computer_team` always evaluates to Truthy value, this condition will be True always.

By using the `in` operator, we are making sure that `board[move]` is in the list of items that follows, which contains `user_team` and `computer_team`. If it is not in that list, it will return False.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the order that Python evaluates those statements. When grouped your way, I can see why it evaluates to true, I just thought it would evaluate the or statement first and then the equals sign, but I was mixing that up with how Python reads the code when there are multiple comparison operators in the same line!  Also, thanks for that new use of lists. (:

Comment: I plan to, as soon as timer is done. (I've got like 30 seconds before I can accept an answer) Thanks for the help!